# Function to get the id of uploaded audio files to use in [playlist] shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am setting up a playlist using the [playlist] shortcode on the homepage of a wordpress website, in the back end I have setup inputs for the user to use the media uploader to upload the audio files that they want on the playlist.

The issue I can't seem to find out if there is a way to collect the ID's of the audio files that the user has input which I would then store in a variable as an array, so I can echo that variable in the playlist shortcode; for example, [playlist ids="'.$songs."]. This is something that I am placing in `front-page.php`.

Basically, I just don't know if there is a way to get the audio ID of an audio file

This is how I am trying to place it in but obviously this would only collect the src of the songs uploaded where I need to get their ID's so I am trying to figure out if its possible to do that.

```
$playlistOne = get_option('playlist_file_one');

$playlistTwo = get_option('playlist_file_two');

$playlistThree = get_option('playlist_file_three');

$playlist = array($playlistOne, $playlistTwo, $playlistThree );

echo do_shortcode('[playlist ids="'.$playlist.'"]');
```

I need the output to be the IDs of the audio files uploaded to the media player, not the src of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to go about it.

```
$playlist = esc_attr(get_option('playlist_files') );
$playlistId = attachment_url_to_postid( $playlist );
echo do_shortcode('[playlist ids="'.$playlistId.'"]');
```